# Storing, Streaming videos and handling requests using REST APIs

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, go, video-streaming, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a web server(REST APIs), which should be able to store, organise and stream videos for a client request.

My confusion:

- How should a user can upload videos. From research, I decided that I would store all the metadata for the videos in database(google datastore), and all the video files in separate storage(Google cloud storage). Now, to upload videos, what is the proper way?
- Once a video is uploaded and stored, how will the streaming will happen. Suppose a user make a request to watch a video, server will get a http request for that. But how to stream videos? Is there any service for this? Because using http streaming directly in code affects performance I guess.

From my understanding, I want to use a service which should be able to stream videos from my storage to a client upon the server's request. I guessed the server should make request to this "video streaming service" only after verifying the user credentials.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en and look up "signed URLS"

Comment: Ask just one question at a time please.

Comment: Well! I am a naive. I thought that asking "Whats your name?" and "Where do you live?" together makes sense. Thanks for your bit.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 (how to enable customers to upload objects), signed URLs are a good bet.

Question 2 is a lot bigger. Depending on your needs you could simply point clients to GCS video files, but modern media serving is a bit more advanced than that. You may want to look into using GCE with a streaming video service, for example something like [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine). Google offers a click-to-deploy experience for it: http://cloud.google.com/tryitnow/wowza

(Keep in mind that Wowza is a separate products requiring a paid license. I don't have any experience with it and neither advocate for nor disapprove of it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a beginner in web programming, so confused at some bits. I am going to try this and will update.